# c++ coroutines temporaries in co_await expressions

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I'm wondering whether co_awaiting a coroutine with a temporary captured by reference is valid or not. So is the following code valid, I guess should the compiler put the temporary in the coroutine frame as for local variables:

```
task g(const S&);

task f() {
    co_await g(S{});
}
```

On clang and msvc (https://godbolt.org/z/HqHae8), the temporary seems to be detroyed after g is resumed, whether on gcc (https://godbolt.org/z/hFWvU-) it seems that the temporary is destroyed after initial suspend.

Comment: Temporaries are destroyed at the end of the full expression. Without coroutines it means after the ;. With your example I think it has to be after the coroutine resumed, that co_await expression ends only after the resume.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSVC and Clang are right, temporaries are destroyed at the end of the full-expression.

For GCC, this is bug [95599](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95599). Apparently this bug is in the process of being fixed.